# Data Loader does not open on OS X El Captain

Tags: data-loader, java, mac-os-x

Does anyone have similar issue opening Data Laoder on MAC OS X El Capitan?

Comment: What version of Java do you have installed?

Comment: I have installed 1.7.0_60

Comment: Hi Coffee, Did you happen to have the same problem?

Comment: Did anyone happen to have solution for this yet?

Comment: I am still struck with this issue. Can you up vote and get more attention to get a solution from experts.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I have created an idea with SalesForce if you want to up vote that. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DrWLAA0

Comment: El Capitan is officially out, but this issue seems to be still persists. Anyone experienced the same?